# fpdf/php sorting data in the table

Tags: fpdf

Hello i have a student table divided by student category (graduate/undergraduate/postgraduate) and sorted by date. We just implemented that within each category students are grouped by their degree field (PhD, MSc, BSc...) and than sorted by date. What i would like to do and can't figure out is how to is to show 'degree' name in a row before listing students.
so should be, for example:
graduate students
PhD
names 2019
names2018
names2000
MsC
names 2019
names2018
names2000

postgraduates
Fellowship:
names
names
names

This is what I have:

function SASTable($header, $data, $report_type )
    {

```
    $this->SetWidths(array(31, 21, 24, 13, 15, 27, 25, 34));

    $this->SetFont('Helvetica','B',10);
    $this->Row(array( $header[0], $header[1],$header[2],$header[3],$header[4],$header[5],$header[6], $header[7]   ) );

    $this->SetFont('Helvetica','',10);

    $BSc_counter = 0;
    $MSc_counter = 0;
    $PhD_counter = 0;
    $MD_counter = 0;

    foreach($data as $row){

        if( $report_type == 5 && $row[100] )
            $this->SetFont('Helvetica','IU',10);
        else
            $this->SetFont('Helvetica','',10);   

        $this->Row(array( $row[0], $row[1], $row[3],$row[4],$row[5],$row[6], $row[7], $row[8]) );

        // Display description here
        if( $row[9] <> null  ){
            $this->SetFont('Helvetica','I',10);     
            // $this->Cell(0,7, ' * ' .$row[9] ,1, 1, 'L' );
            // $this->Cell(0,7,  ' * '. $row[0] .' '. $row[9] ,0 , 1, 'L' );    
            $this->SetFillColor(255,255,255);
            $this->SetLineWidth(0.1);
            $this->Ln(0);
            $this->MultiCell(0,4, ' * '.$row[9], 1,'L',1); 

            $this->SetFont('Helvetica','',10);


// 3005 Students_Supervised Graduate Student Supervisory Committees 
    if (isset($student_supervised_graduate_supervisory_committees[0])  && is_array( $student_supervised_graduate_supervisory_committees )){ 
        $pdf->CheckBottomBreak2();
        $pdf->SubSectionTitle('Graduate Student Supervisory Committee ');
        $header=array('Student Name', 'Degree',  'Time commitment','Start' ,'End', 'Supervisor or Supervisory role', 'Co - supervision', 'Program' );


        $pdf->SASTable($header, $student_supervised_graduate_supervisory_committees, $report_type  );  
        // Display subscript
        // $pdf->OneColumnSASTable( $student_supervised_graduate_supervisory_committees ); 
        $pdf->Ln(7);
    }   


    // 3006 Students_Supervised Examination Committees 
    if (isset($student_supervised_examination_committees[0])  && is_array( $student_supervised_examination_committees )){ 
        /* Check if Bottom of page is reach before adding a new page */ 
      $pdf->CheckBottomBreak2();
        $pdf->SubSectionTitle('Examination Committee');
        $header=array('Student Name', 'Degree',  'Time commitment','Start' ,'End', 'Supervisor or Supervisory role', 'Co - supervision', 'Program' );


        $pdf->SASTable($header, $student_supervised_examination_committees, $report_type );  
        // Display subscript
        // $pdf->OneColumnSASTable( $student_supervised_examination_committees ); 
        $pdf->Ln(7);

    } 


    //  3004 Students_Supervised Postgraduate Students Supervised
    if (isset($student_supervised_postgraduates[0])  && is_array( $student_supervised_postgraduates )){ 
            /* Check if Bottom of page is reach before adding a new page */ 
      $pdf->CheckBottomBreak2();
        $pdf->SubSectionTitle('Postgraduate Students Supervised (Project and research laboratory supervision)');
        $header=array('Student Name', 'Degree', 'Time commitment','Start' ,'End', 'Supervisor or Supervisory role', 'Co - supervision', 'Program' );


        $pdf->SASTable($header, $student_supervised_postgraduates, $report_type );  
         // Display subscript
        // $pdf->OneColumnSASTable( $student_supervised_postgraduates ); 
        $pdf->Ln(7);
    } 


    //  3001 Students_Supervised Undergraduate Students
    if (isset($student_supervised_undergraduates[0])  && is_array( $student_supervised_undergraduates )){ 
          $pdf->CheckBottomBreak2();
       $pdf->SubSectionTitle('MD Undergraduate Students');
        $header=array('Student Name', 'Degree',  'Time commitment','Start' ,'End', 'Supervisor or Supervisory role', 'Co - supervision', 'Program' );

        $pdf->SASTable($header, $student_supervised_undergraduates, $report_type );  

        // Display subscript
        // $pdf->OneColumnSASTable( $student_supervised_undergraduates );
        $pdf->Ln(7);
    }   


    //  3002 Students_Supervised Other Undergraduate
    if (isset($student_supervised_other_undergraduates[0])  && is_array( $student_supervised_other_undergraduates )){ 
          $pdf->CheckBottomBreak2();
      $pdf->SubSectionTitle('Other Undergraduate Students');
        $header=array('Student name', 'Degree',  'Time commitment','Start' ,'End', 'Supervisor or Supervisory role', 'Co - supervision', 'Program' );


        $pdf->SASTable($header, $student_supervised_other_undergraduates, $report_type );
        // Display subscript
        // $pdf->OneColumnSASTable( $student_supervised_other_undergraduates ); 
        $pdf->Ln(7);

    }
```